# Uber Car Seat/Family Orlando

Tags: transportation, children, child-safety-seats, ride-sharing, orlando

We will be travelling to the Orlando area with our 3-year-old son and are trying to figure out local transportation. Uber seems to have services called Uber Family and Uber Car Seat, and they are available in Orlando. However, I find conflicting information on specific availability. Their [blog post](https://www.uber.com/blog/orlando/introducing-uberfamily-to-orlando/) from 2016 states:

> SERVICE AREAS You will be able to request an uberFAMILY car in the following areas:
>
> - MCO Airport
> - Disney Theme Parks/Resorts
> - I-Drive Resorts
> - Universal Theme Park/Resorts
> - SeaWorld Theme Park/Resorts
> - Four Corners Resorts

But that's a few years ago. The issue is that those are our likely destinations, but our hotel is not in those areas. So does it mean we can get a car with car seat from airport to hotel, but not on the way back, for example?

They have a [different website](https://www.uber.com/cities/orlando/vehicle-options/economy/) that does not list these area restrictions, but I don't know if their Orlando area includes Kissimmee, where we will be staying:

> What to expect with UberFAMILY: In the app, move the toggle to the UberFAMILY option. If you’re at Orlando International Airport (MCO), a luxury vehicle will pick you up. If you’re anywhere else in Orlando, an uberX vehicle with a car seat will take you where you’re going.

I have contacted Uber Support and received a generic response that did not even attempt to answer this question.

**Can I order an Uber with car seat anywhere in the Orlando area (including Kissimmee)?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost exactly a year ago I was in Orlando doing exactly this. We never had any issue requesting cars with car seats anywhere in Orlando, to go anywhere in Orlando. We stayed in town, not at any Disney resorts.

Orlando basically survives on the tourism industry and there's enough demand there for Uber drivers to be available at most times.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest Kidmoto in Orlando and Port Canaveral and surrounding areas. They provide up to 4 child car seats in a vehicle. Front-facing, rear-facing and booster seats, all pre-harnessed and pre-installed. Try Kidmoto in Orlando.

(**Affiliation**:  I am the Founder of Kidmoto Technologies)

Comment: Since you’re the CEO of this company, can you at least disclose your affiliation instead of saying “they?”

Comment: https://www.crunchbase.com/person/nelson-nigel - Nelson. Please disclose affiliation on SE sites.

Comment: I am sorry, I discovered Stack Exchange yesterday and I am unaware and new to these types of forums. Yes I am the Founder and CEO. How can I make the correction? I apologise for any misrepresentation.

Comment: @NelsonNigel simply edit the original post.

Comment: @NelsonNigel did it for you. Have a read of the [help], it'll assist a lot. Thanks!

Comment: hello @MarkMayo thanks for the help, much appreciated. I am getting the hang of this. cheers